# string concatenation with nested ternary operator ignores the string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I found differences between the following two statements.

```
message = "a is " + "greater than" if a > 10 else "less than" if a <10 else "equal to" + " 10"
```

and

```
message = "a is " + ("greater than" if a > 10 else ("less than" if a <10 else "equal to")) + " 10"
```

Could someone explain what is happening here

Comment: The first is interpreted as `("a is " + "greater than") if a > 10 else "less than" if a <10 else ("equal to" + " 10")`. That's why you have the option of grouping parts of your expression with parentheses.

Comment: [Conditional expressions have the lowest priority of all Python operations.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first is interpreted as:

```
("a is "+"greater than") if a > 10 else "less than" if a < 10 else ("equal to"+" 10")
```

See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions): "Conditional expressions have the lowest priority of all Python operations."

That's why you have the option of grouping parts of your expression with parentheses.

Comment: Furthermore, see [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) for a complete order of the operators.